# Software Suggestions For Remote Access To One Private Network From Another Private Network

Tags: remote-access

I'm currently incrementally developing a piece of software for a small business which is located 50 - 60 kilometres from where I live. The employees of the company are not very tech-savy which means I regularly have to be on site myself to perform software installs and updates.

To save travelling for myself and costs for the company, it would be brilliant if I could remotely access their network and perform this work from home.

The company has no public IP address and all the machines I require access to are in a private subnet of their network.

Would anyone be able to recommend an affordable (or even free) VPN solution that allows for remote administration with a graphical front-end thats matches my requirements (i.e. accessing one private network from another, with no company owned public VPN server)?

I have some minor experience with spme high-end UTM devices with VPNs built in but I have little or no knowledge of other products, such as OpenVPN.

Comment: The first half of your question is great, but once you start offering a solution (suggesting VPN), you turn the question into an XY Question.  See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/214212

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a solution like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) hosted on a server, [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com) works as well, as does [Remote Desktop Connection](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network) (as long as you remember to forward the proper ports), or even a service such as [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) or [GoToMyPC](http://www.gotomypc.com).  You don't necessarily need a VPN, any remote desktop protocol should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kruug, the free version of LogMeIn is exactly what I'm looking for and seems very straight forward and simple to use!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Remote Utilities](http://www.remoteutilities.com). It provides secure connection to a remote computer. In addition, they have a self-hosted solution so you can deploy your own intermediary server. Alternatively you can go with the manufacturer's servers (like TeamViewer or Logmeein).